# Determine $f(x, y)$ if $f(x + y, x - y) = xy + y^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Determine $f(x, y)$ if $f(x + y, x - y) = xy + y^2$.

I have been doing similar problems, but can't get my head around this one. I'd rather get a tip instead of the full answer. Thanks to anyone who contributes.

**My Solution After Tips:**

Let $u = x + y$ and $ v = x - y$. Then $ x = u - y $ and $ y = x - v $. From these equations, we have that

$ x = u - y = u - (x - v) \rightarrow x = u - x + v \rightarrow 2x = u + v \Rightarrow x = (u + v)/2 $.

Similarly, $u - v = (x + y) - (x - y) = x + y - x + y = 2y \Rightarrow y = (u - v)/2$.

Substituting, we get

$$ f(u, v) = (\frac{u + v}{2})(\frac{u - v}{2}) + (\frac{u + v}{2})^2 $$

> $$ f(u, v) = \frac{u^2 - uv}{2} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it directly as follows:

- $f(x+y,x-y) = xy+y^2 = (x+y)y$

Now, write

- $y = \frac{1}{2}((x+y)-(x-y))$

It follows:

$$f(x+y,x-y)= (x+y)\cdot \frac{1}{2}((x+y)-(x-y)) = \frac{1}{2}\left( (x+y)^2 - (x+y)(x-y)\right)$$ $$\Rightarrow f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2-xy)$$

Comment: How would you think about this substitution for y in the first place? Just intuition?

Comment: @VictorS. When looking at the expression $(x+y)y$, the next question is, how to express $y$ in terms of $x+y$ and $x-y$. So, you either just "see" ("intuite") or know it or you may set up $a(x+y) +b(x-y) =0\cdot x +1\cdot y$ and find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I just understood your reasoning for why one would want this substitution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let $u = x+y, v = x-y$.

Now express each of $x$ and $y$ in terms of only $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I added my solution to the original question. Could you verify, please?

Comment: Not sure I follow your process.  But what I do gives the same result as you got:
$$
f(u,v) = f(x+y, x-y) = xy + y^2 = [(u+v)/2] \; [(u-v)/2] + [(u-v)/2]^2 = (u^2 - v^2)/4 + (u^2 - 2uv + v^2)/4,
$$
and the like terms can be collected.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle(x,y)=\left(\frac{x+y}2+\frac{x-y}2,\frac{x+y}2-\frac{x-y}2\right)$

Comment: I added my solution to the original question. Could you verify, please?

Comment: No, that is not correct. The correct answer is one quarter of that: $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-xy}2$. You can check that, with this function, you indeed have $f(x+y,x-y)=xy+y^2$.